# Dynamics CRM 2013 - Save PDF format custom SSRS report

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to store generated PDF from CRM report using javascript.

I got this [reference](http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2012/11/dynamics-crm-2011-creating-e-mail.html), which generates PDF and email. But I want to store it to my local. How can I do that?

Please help me on this

Comment: Are you on-premise ?

Comment: @Alex yes, it is on-premise

Answer (score 1):

You can link straight to SSRS, which in turn can be told to spit out the report as PDF (it will be handled like any direct link to a PDF).

The URL looks like this:

```
<SSRS_host>/ReportServer?<reportname>&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:Format=pdf&<report_params>
```

The focus being the `&rs:Format=pdf`.

`<report_params>` should be `Param1=Value1&Param2=Value2` and is used to fill the (obviously) report parameters.

Be careful about permissions:

- If you link from Javascript, every user who can see the link must also be given permissions on SSRS (otherwise: 403 Forbidden)
- If you link from SDK (i.e. a plugin or an external assembly) then you can impersonate a "service user" (this is how we do this: a web service living alongside CRM which handles requests for PDFs)

[AFAIK This is not applicable to CRM Online since you cannot get to SQL/SSRS directly]